# Jenssegers - How to find all documents in collection with ID

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I have collections of Books and Users. Each book has a user_id which is the ObjectId of a User. When a user is logged in I want to list all of their books. How could I find all documents in the books collection with a user_id equal to the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$books = Book::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

$user_id is the id of the user that is logged in.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error here?. What are you using for authentication? dd($user_id) to check what is the user id of the user that is logged in